# Image is not displaying in IE

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a site that is managed with asp.net. I want to display an image in one of my web page but that image can not be viewed in Internet Explorer but other browsers can display it, although the path is correct.

```
<asp:Image ID="PageImage" runat="server" ImageUrl ="~/images/PageImage.png" />
```

Can any body help to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried absolute path instead of relative? mysite.com/images/PageImage.png for instance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `didn't use` the `CMYK` colorspace when creating the image, 
which `IE can't handle`. `Saving` it in `RGB` colorspace should `fix the problem` (for example, in Adobe Photoshop, use the "Save for web..." option).

**Edit:**

I tried `resaving` the `image in GIMP`, and it `indeed works now in IE for me`.

learn more here [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/79a9edc7-70f6-4d08-9ae3-5a439b0f6356/ie-does-not-display-images?forum=ieitpropriorver)